# Regular Expression for an mail address

Tags: regex

```
"Max Mustermann" <max.mustermann@domain.com>
max.mustermann@domain.com
Max <max.mustermann@domain.com>
```

I need a regular Expression which matches everthing outside the arrow brackets (including the brackets).
The Match should be removed afterwards.

After the replacement it should look like this:

```
"Max Mustermann" <max.mustermann@domain.com> => max.mustermann@domain.com
```

Comment: Although not the same question, note that fully parsing all forms of email addresses is hard, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to search for

```
[^<]*<([^>]*)>.*
```

and replace that with `\1` or `$1`, depending on your regex engine.

This removes everything until the first `<` and everything from the next `>` until the end of the string.

Let's just hope that there will be no brackets inside the quoted names.

Comment: it does not really. For example, naked `email@domain.com` does not match.

Comment: because it should extract email address from any email, including without `<>` - this is listed as line 2 in question.

Comment: @mvp: OK, so what exactly should be matched and removed from `max.mustermann@domain.com`?

Comment: this is in my answer - http://fiddle.re/ub81 (click Perl or Java to see examples)

Comment: Point is that on input we have email address that could be in all kinds of weird formats (with descriptive user name, with angle brackets or without), and on output we want email in simplest possible format `user@domain.com`.

Comment: @mvp: Where does it say that in the question?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but beware that it is very [simplified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address):

```
(?:[^<]*<)?([^>]+).*
```

Answer of email will be in `$1`.

For example, in Perl use:

```
$email =~ s/(?:[^<]*<)?([^>]+).*/$1/;
```

See [RegexPlanet online demo](http://fiddle.re/ub81).

Comment: Hi, the expression does not work the result is the following string max.mustermann@domain.com>

Comment: fixed, added link to fiddle.re with lots of testing inputs.